# SQL show only results that have both items

Tags: sql, relational-division

I have a SQL table with names and fruits that the persons ate.
I only want the result to show the Names of people who ate both an apple and a banana. But if i use "Where Item='Banana' and item='Apple', the data shows nothing.
If i use: Where item in('banana','apple'), it shows the result as shown in the table.

| Name | Item |
| --- | --- |
| John | Apple |
| David | Banana |
| John | Banana |

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a GROUP BY and then select only the person who has eaten 2 fruits from the list, ie both of them

> ```
> CREATE TABLE eaten(
> person VARCHAR (10),
> fruit VARCHAR (10));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO eaten VALUES
> ('John','apple'),
> ('Bill','apple'),
> ('Bill','pear'),
> ('David','banana'),
> ('David','banana'),
> ('John','banana');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT person
> FROM eaten
> WHERE fruit IN ('apple','banana')
> GROUP BY person
> HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) =2;
> ```

> ```
> | person |
> | :----- |
> | John   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b5738e16a6b055692c732a87b369930)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` with an `EXISTS` clause to get what you need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
           FROM table1 a
          WHERE a.Item = 'Apple'
            AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                          FROM table1 b
                         WHERE b.Item = 'Banana'
                           AND b.Name = a.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE_Apple AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM Table where Item = 'Apple'
)
,
CTE_Banana AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Item = 'Banana'

)
SELECT 
           A.Name 
FROM 
           CTE_Apple AS A
    JOIN
           CTE_Banana AS B ON B.Name = A.Name
```

Basically create two sub-sets of the data and join them together where the data intersects.  There are plenty of other ways to do this but I find CTE (Common Table Expressions) the most elegant

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery should work in any RDBMS:

```
select distinct Name 
from table_name
where Item = 'Apple'
and Name in 
(select Name from table_name where Item = 'Banana');
```